# Console Game "Epic Dungeon"

Tags: c++, beginner, game

Made a console game in C++ called "Epic dungeon", which my friend did a year ago in JS. I decided to do it in order to gain experience (in fact, I did it because I would have stopped learning C++ if I hadn't done something, because studying for so long and not doing anything can quickly get boring) I did it without using OOP, because I still don't know it well. At times it may seem to you that I was on LSD, but this is not so. I'll immediately answer the question: "Why did I make the choose variable char?" Because if you make the variable int and write any character (you can do it accidentally and it will be a shame because you have to restart) then infinite recursion of functions will go, and if it is char then this will not happen. I look forward to criticism of the game and my code :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

double hp = 60.0, damage = 15.0, shield = 100.0;
double en_hp = 50.0, en_damage = 10.0, en_shield = 100.0;
double boss_hp = 1000.0, boss_damage = 250.0, boss_shield = 150.0;
int boss_lvl = 1;
int en_level = 1, hero_level = 1, energy = 6, gold = 0, skills = 0;
int experience = 0, new_lvl_xp = 10;
double en_fight_hp = en_hp;
double hero_fight_hp = hp;
int fight_energy = energy;
double boss_fight_hp = boss_hp;


int startGame();                                    //Game start functionality
void mainMenu();                                    //Main menu
void menuSkills();                                  //Skill menu
void menuHero();                                    //Hero menu
void menuLvl();                                     //Progress menu
void menuDev();                                     //Creators menu

void imgFightBoss();                                //Boss Fight Visual
void imgFightNPC();                                 //Dungeon NPC combat visual
double fightNPC(double x, double y, double z);      //Functionality of the fight with NPCs from the dungeon
double fightHeroNpc(double x, double y, double z);  //The functionality of the battle with the Hero in the dungeon

void fightAttack();                                 //Simple attack function in combat
void fightDodge();                                  //Dodge attack function in combat
void fightShield();                                 //Shield function in battle
void fightHeal();                                   //Combat healing function

void fightAttackBoss();                             //Simple attack function in boss fight
void fightDodgeBoss();                              //Dodge attack function in boss fight
void fightShieldBoss();                             //Shield function in boss fight
void fightHealBoss();                               //Boss Fight Healing Function

void winBattleNPC();                                //Victory in a battle with an NPC
void winBattleBoss();                               //Winning a Boss Fight


int main() {
    system("chcp 1251>nul");
    startGame();
    return 0;
}


void mainMenu() {               //Main menu with a choice of actions
    cout << "Choose an action:\nGo to the boss: 1\nGo to the dungeon: 2\nSkills: 3\nHero characteristics: 4\nExit to the start menu: 5\n";
    char choose;
    cin >> choose;
    switch (choose) {
        case '1':
            imgFightBoss();
            break;
        case '2':
            imgFightNPC();
            break;
        case '3':
            menuSkills();
            break;
        case '4':
            
            menuHero();
            break;
        case '5':
            startGame();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tI do not understand what you want?\n";
            mainMenu();
            break;
    }

}

int startGame() {               //Game start functionality
    cout << "Start the game: 1\nQuit the game: 2\nCreators: 3\n";
    char choose;
    cin >> choose;
    switch (choose) {
        case '1':
            mainMenu();
            break;
        case '2':
            return 0;
            break;
        case '3':
            menuDev();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tI don't understand what is required!\n";
            startGame();
    }
    
}


    
void menuSkills() {             //Skills menu
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  Skill points: " << skills << "\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tHealth: " << hp << " Damage: " << damage << " Protection: " << shield << "\n";
    cout << "Select an action:\nImprove health skill: 1\nIncrease attack skill: 2\nIncrease Armor Skill: 3\nBack: 4\n";
    char choose;
    cin >> choose;
    switch (choose) {
        case '1':
            if (skills >= 1) {
                hp += 10.0;
                skills -= 1;
                hero_fight_hp = hp;
                menuSkills();
            }   
            else {
                cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   Not enough skill points!\n";
                menuSkills();
            }
            break;
        case '2':
            if (skills >= 1) {
                damage += 3.0;
                skills -= 1;
                menuSkills();
            }
            else {
                cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   Not enough skill points!\n";
                menuSkills();
            }
            break;
        case '3':
            if (skills >= 1) {
                if (shield < 500) {
                    shield += 12.5;
                    skills -= 1;
                    menuSkills();
                }
                else {
                    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tMaximum armor value reached!\n";
                    menuSkills();
                }
            }
            else {
                cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   Not enough skill points!\n";
                menuSkills();
            }
            break;
        case '4':
            mainMenu();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tI don't understand what is required of me\n";
            menuSkills();
            break;
    }
}
void menuHero() {           //Hero menu
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t ____________________\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|                    |\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t  Level:         " << hero_level << "\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t  Skill points:  " << skills << "\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t  Health:        " << hp << "\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t  Damage:        " << damage << "\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t  Protection:    " << shield << "\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|____________________|\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\tView character level progress: 1\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\tExit to the main menu:                 2\n";
    char choose;
    cin >> choose;
    switch (choose) {
        case '1':
            menuLvl();
            break;
        case '2':
            mainMenu();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    I don't understand what is required of me\n";
            menuHero();
            break;
    }
}
void menuLvl() {
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t ___________________\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|                   |\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t      Level: " << hero_level << "\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   Level progress:\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t        " << experience << "/" << new_lvl_xp << "\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|___________________|\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t       Back: 1\n";
    char choose;
    cin >> choose;
    switch (choose) {
        case '1':
            menuHero();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    I don't understand what is required of me\n";
            menuLvl();

    }
}


void menuDev() {
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t ____________________\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|                    |\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t      Idea creator: \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t   Rakhimzhanov Gleb\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t      Developer: \n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t       TuleKr1s\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t|____________________|\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t     Back: 1\n";
    char choose;
    cin >> choose;
    switch (choose) {
    case '1':
        startGame();
        break;
    default:
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t    I don't understand what is required of me\n";
        menuDev();

    }
}

void imgFightNPC() {                //displaying information on the battle with npc (yes, I know it's so awful)
    if (en_fight_hp > 0) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t _______________________________________\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                            YOU\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                         energy: " << fight_energy << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        hp      : " << hero_fight_hp << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        power   : " << damage << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        shield  : " << shield << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t         __                                   __\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |=================|  |============|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |Attack:         1|  |Shield:    3|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |=================|  |============|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |Attack + Dodge: 2|  |Healing:   4|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |=================|  |============|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |__                                   __|\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                             DEVIL\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                          level: " << en_level << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        hp      : " << en_fight_hp << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        power   : " << en_damage << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        shield  : " << en_shield << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|_______________________________________|\n";
        char choose;
        cin >> choose;
        switch (choose) {
        case '1':           //attack

            fightAttack();
            imgFightNPC();
            break;
        case '2':           //attack + dodge

            fightDodge();
            imgFightNPC();
            break;
        case '3':           //shield

            fightShield();
            imgFightNPC();
            break;
        case '4':           //healing

            fightHeal();
            imgFightNPC();
            break;
        default:

            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t  I don't understand what is required of me\n";
            imgFightNPC();
            break;
        }
    }
    else {

        winBattleNPC();
        mainMenu();

    }
}
string boss_kind = "Satan";
void imgFightBoss() {                       //displaying information on the battle with boss

    if (boss_lvl > 3) {

        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tYou have defeated all possible bosses!\n";
        mainMenu();

    }


    if (boss_fight_hp > 0) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t _______________________________________\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                            YOU\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                         energy: " << fight_energy << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        hp      : " << hero_fight_hp << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        power   : " << damage << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        shield  : " << shield << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t         __                                   __\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |=================|  |============|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |Attack:         1|  |Shield:    3|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |=================|  |============|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |Attack + Dodge: 2|  |Healing:   4|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |  |=================|  |============|  |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t        |__                                   __|\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                            BOSS\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                         kind: " << boss_kind << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        hp      : " << boss_fight_hp << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        power   : " << boss_damage << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t                        shield  : " << boss_shield << "\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|                                       |\n";
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t|_______________________________________|\n";
        char choose;
        cin >> choose;
        switch (choose) {
        case '1':           //attack

            fightAttackBoss();
            imgFightBoss();

            break;
        case '2':           //attack + dodge

            fightDodgeBoss();
            imgFightBoss();

            break;
        case '3':           //shield

            fightShieldBoss();
            imgFightBoss();

            break;
        case '4':           //healing

            fightHealBoss();
            imgFightBoss();

            break;
        default:

            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t  I don't understand what is required of me!\n";
            imgFightNPC();
            break;
        }
    }
    else {

        winBattleBoss();
        mainMenu();

    }
}

void fightAttack() {                //attack function

    if (fight_energy == 0) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\tNot enough energy! Use your shield to boost her!\n";
        imgFightNPC();
    }

    en_fight_hp = fightNPC(en_fight_hp, damage, en_shield);
    hero_fight_hp = fightHeroNpc(hero_fight_hp, en_damage, shield);
    --fight_energy;

    if (hero_fight_hp <= 0 && en_fight_hp > 0) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tYou have failed!\n";
        fight_energy = energy;
        hero_fight_hp = hp;
        en_fight_hp = en_hp;
        mainMenu();
    }

}

void fightAttackBoss() {            //attack function with boss
    if (fight_energy == 0) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\tNot enough energy! Use your shield to boost her!\n";
        imgFightBoss();
    }

    boss_fight_hp = fightNPC(boss_fight_hp, damage, boss_shield);
    hero_fight_hp = fightHeroNpc(hero_fight_hp, boss_damage, shield);
    --fight_energy;

    if (hero_fight_hp <= 0 && boss_fight_hp > 0) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tYou have failed!\n";
        fight_energy = energy;
        hero_fight_hp = hp;
        boss_fight_hp = boss_hp;
        mainMenu();
    }
}

void fightDodge() {                 //attack + dodge function

    if (fight_energy <= 1) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\tNot enough energy! Use your shield to boost her!\n";
        imgFightNPC();
    }

    en_fight_hp = fightNPC(en_fight_hp, damage, en_shield);
    fight_energy -= 2;


}

void fightDodgeBoss() {             //attack + dodge funcion with boss
    if (fight_energy <= 1) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\tNot enough energy! Use your shield to boost her!\n";
        imgFightBoss();
    }

    boss_fight_hp = fightNPC(boss_fight_hp, damage, boss_shield);
    fight_energy -= 2;

}

void fightShield() {                //shield function

    ++fight_energy;
    hero_fight_hp = fightHeroNpc(hero_fight_hp, en_damage, shield);

    if (hero_fight_hp <= 0 && en_fight_hp > 0) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tYou have failed!\n";
        fight_energy = energy;
        hero_fight_hp = hp;
        en_fight_hp = en_hp;
        mainMenu();
    }

}

void fightShieldBoss() {

    ++fight_energy;
    hero_fight_hp = fightHeroNpc(hero_fight_hp, boss_damage, shield);

    if (hero_fight_hp <= 0 && boss_fight_hp > 0) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tYou have failed!\n";
        fight_energy = energy;
        hero_fight_hp = hp;
        boss_fight_hp = boss_hp;
        mainMenu();
    }

}

void fightHeal() {                  //healing function

    if (fight_energy <= 1) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\tNot enough energy! Use your shield to boost her!\n";
        imgFightNPC();
    }

    hero_fight_hp += 20.0;
    fight_energy -= 2;

}

void fightHealBoss() {              //healing function with boss

    if (fight_energy <= 1) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\tNot enough energy! Use your shield to boost her!\n";
        imgFightBoss();
    }

    hero_fight_hp += 100.0;
    fight_energy -= 2;

}

void winBattleNPC() {               //battle victory function with NPC

    int xp = rand() % 5 + 1;            //obtained in battle
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t  You have won! Received:\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t     Skill points: 5\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t     Experience: " << xp << "\n";
    experience += xp;                   //received in battle, add to the total amount
    if (experience >= new_lvl_xp) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tYou've got a new level!\n";
        ++hero_level;
        experience -= new_lvl_xp;
        new_lvl_xp += (new_lvl_xp / 4);
    }
    en_hp += 40;
    en_damage += 15;
    ++en_level;
    skills += 5;
    fight_energy = energy;
    en_fight_hp = en_hp;
    hero_fight_hp = hp;


}

void winBattleBoss() {              //battle victory function with Boss


    int xp = rand() % 10 + 10;          //obtained in battle
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t  You have won! Received:\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t     Skill points: 10\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t     Experience: " << xp << "\n";
    experience += xp;                   //received in battle, add to the total amount
    if (experience >= new_lvl_xp) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tYou've got a new level\n";
        ++hero_level;
        experience -= new_lvl_xp;
        new_lvl_xp += (new_lvl_xp / 4);
    }
    ++boss_lvl;

    if (boss_lvl == 1) {
        boss_kind = "Satan";
    }
    else if (boss_lvl == 2) {
        boss_kind = "Lucifer";
        boss_hp = 2000;
        boss_damage = 500;
        boss_shield = 200;
    }
    else if (boss_lvl == 3) {
        boss_kind = "Leviathan";
        boss_hp = 4000;
        boss_damage = 800;
        boss_shield = 300;
    }

    if (boss_lvl > 3) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tCongratulations! Defeated all possible bosses!\n";
    }
    skills += 10;
    fight_energy = energy;
    boss_fight_hp = boss_hp;
    hero_fight_hp = hp;


}

//I know it could be easier, but it's easier for me this way (I love shit code)

double fightNPC(double x, double y, double z) {             //change enemy hp in fight
    x -= y * (1 - z / 1000);                                    //x - enemy hp, y - hero damage, z - enemy shield
    return x;
}
double fightHeroNpc(double x, double y, double z) {         //change hero hp in fight
    x -= y * (1 - z / 1000);                                    //x - hero hp, y - enemy damage, z - hero shield
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a superficial review for now:

- If you really want to learn C++, you should start with OOP included. Whereas C++ is technically a multi-paradigm language, most of the reason to use C++ over C is for its OOP.
- Conversely, if you don't actually care about OOP, this should be C and not C++ (it's almost C anyway).
- Regardless of whether you use C or C++, encapsulating your list of game state variables in a re-entrant struct instead of globals would benefit the structure of your program.
- Formatting with deeply-nested `\t` characters is ill-advised. Tabs are environmentally dependent, so it might look great on your console and garbage on someone else's. Prefer spaces instead.

Comment: `...Prefer spaces instead [of tabs]` This!